# Right Justify with left vertical align

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to right justify my text with left vertical alignment. 
For example I want my text to appear like this:

```
                                                         bla bla bla 
                                                         bla bla
                                                         bla bla bla bla
```

Instead of this:

```
                                                         bla bla bla 
                                                             bla bla
                                                     bla bla bla bla
```

How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You mean inside `align` environment? Just put `&` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: No that was not inside an align environment. David posted exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
zzz\\
zzzzz\\
z
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
```

Comment: Or with `varwidth`

Comment: @egreg you could post a varwidth answer and try to grab the green tick (although mostly I see this for addresses and similar constructs where manual linebreaking is what's wanted anyway)